# How can I grab all terms beginning with '#'?

Tags: python, regex, hashtag

I have a string like so: `"sometext #Syrup #nshit #thebluntislit"`

and i want to get a list of all terms starting with '#'

I used the following code:

```
import re
line = "blahblahblah #Syrup #nshit #thebluntislit"
ht = re.search(r'#\w*', line)
ht = ht.group(0)
print ht
```

and i get the following:

```
#Syrup
```

I was wondering if there is a way that I could instead get a list like:

```
[#Syrup,#nshit,#thebluntislit]
```

for all terms starting with '#' instead of just the first term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `re.findall()` will do what you want.

```
matches = re.findall(r'#\w*', line)
```

Answer (score 21):

Regular expression is not needed with good programming languages like Python:

```
  hashed = [ word for word in line.split() if word.startswith("#") ]
```

Comment: I call BS. Whether or not regular expressions are needed does not depend on the language, but on the use case. There are good reasons for using a regex, although this might not be one. Anyway, nice answer.

Comment: Python is soo sexy isn't it?! :-)

Comment: well, this only works if all your terms are space delimited. Also, knowing that Mikko has an agenda against regular expressions, I would state that it is not the regular expressions in the mathematical sense, but the braindamaged syntax that is bad.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
compiled = re.compile(r'#\w*')
compiled.findall(line)
```

Output:

```
['#Syrup', '#nshit', '#thebluntislit']
```

But there is a problem. If you search the string like `'blahblahblah #Syrup #nshit #thebluntislit beg#end'`, the output will be `['#Syrup', '#nshit', '#thebluntislit', '#end']`.

This problem may be addressed by using positive lookbehind:

```
compiled = re.compile(r'(?<=\s)#\w*')
```

(it's not possible to use `\b` (word boundary) here since `#` is not among 
`\w` symbols `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` which may constitute the word which boundary is being searched).